# uberspace git deployment with laravel 4.2 and rocketeer 1.2.2

Tags: php, git, laravel, deployment, repository

I have a web application build with laravel 4.2.
And I have a uberspace account. nothing special.
I have also the vendor package rocketeer from anahkiasen for deploy my application to the server.
With laravel 4.1 this isn't a problem.
But after I upgrade to laravel 4.2 I got massive problems when I try to deploy my application.
I got constantly the following error message:

> [ErrorException] Cannot connect to 185.26.156.31:22. Error 10060.

When I try this `artisan deploy --pretend` command I got this response:

```
$ artisan deploy --pretend
Cloning repository in "/var/www/....
git clone --depth 1 -b master "ssh://.../my.git" /var/www/virtual/myaccount/releases/20150209214151
Initializing submodules if any
cd /var/www/virtual/myaccount/releases/20150209214151
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

and then the same:

> [ErrorException] Cannot connect to 185.26.156.31:22. Error 10060.

As I say I know how to deploy a laravel application to a server with a git repository.

> what is very curios - the empty production folder will create at the destination uberspace 
>   server. So it is proved that I have access to this server via SSH and
>   with my private SSH key.

Is there some known issue? Do anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not laravel or rocketeer, it was a SSH Key problem.
It is necessary that the server has a private key in the known hosts file.
It is weird, but the server must knowing himself ... :-/

Comment: I presume this behaviour occurs because you are cloning via `ssh://…`, so you are ssh'ing into your own server. You could clone via the `file://…` protocol and make that configuration obsolete.